# Cannot access git repo using Git for Windows or TortoiseGit

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I do some development work for a friend, who runs his own Linux git server. Everything worked until he decided to harden his server. He decided 1024-bit keys weren't good enough, so I sent him a new 4096-bit public key.

Now I can no longer access the repository from Windows.

The repository url is `ssh://git@1.2.3.4:2000/home/git/code.git` (IP address changed to protect the innocent). Note that ssh runs on port 2000.

Trying to clone the repo from TortoiseGit gives "Server refused our key" in the git window, and "No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey, gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)" in an error dialog.

Trying from Git for Windows bash gives "fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

However, I can happily clone the same repo from a Linux VM running on the same machine, using the same key pair.

I have updated both Git for Windows and TortoiseGit with the latest version today.

[Later] I can actually log into the server from Putty and from Git bash:

```
$ ssh-agent bash

MINGW64 /e/folder
$ ssh-add rsa4096
Identity added: rsa4096 (rsa4096)

MINGW64 /e/folder
$ ssh -p 2000 git@1.2.3.4
Last login: Fri Jan  8 17:11:32 2021 from my.local.machine
```

(Ip addresses and machine names changed)

I can also login using `"C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe" -P 2000` (the GIT_SSH variable is set to `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe`)

Not sure what to try now - help!

Comment: Do you use Pageant? Is the right key loaded? Has your fried already installed the new key? is your old key configured somewhere (e.g., a putty session)?

Comment: What's Pageant? The correct key is specified in the TortoiseGit settings. The key is installed (I can use the repo with the new key from linux). The old key may be installed in a putty session - why would TortoiseGit (and Git for Windows, which uses ssh instead of putty, I think) use a key out of an unrelated putty saved session?

Comment: I suspect the problem may conceivably be with the port not being 22? But it's just a wild guess - it worked before on that port.

Comment: Have put a packet sniffer on the connection. It connects, exchanges a handshake which seems to list the types of key accepted, then it goes all binary.